# Split variable in Ida Pesudo Code

Tags: ida, static-analysis

Sometime the meaning of variable has been changed on the function.

For example from Ida pseudo code:

```
a = price
....
a= tax....
```

In the beginning of function `a` was price and after that `a` is tax.

How can I split a to 2 different variable so I can rename this variable in Ida Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or right-click on the variable and then choose "Force new variable".

IDA documentation: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/cmd_force_lvar.shtml

Comment: Shift+F7 open segment tabs. And there is no `Force new variable` option while right click on variable

Comment: Which version of IDA are you running?

Comment: 7.6 is my version

Comment: I fixed the shortcut. BTW as you can see from the documentation, it's the built-in function to do this and note that: "Currently, only aliasable stack variables can be forced."